# Scatter plot for each column of a DF : generates random number of files

Tags: r, plot, dataframe

I'm currently trying to create a function creating a scatter plot for each column of a dataframe with another column, and putting it into a png file.

The big issue is that running the script at moment A and at moment B with the same dataframe does not creates the same number of files : I may end up with 50 files or 80... It is random and I can't explain it...

No error is printed in the console...

I would like all the columns to be plotted, not only a random subset of them.

Does anyone know what could be the reason of this problem? And how to solve it?

Here's the code :

```
data_analysis_num <- function(variete, centre, dataframe, column_name)
  {

  column <- DataF[,column_name]
  name_folder <- paste('Corr_centre_', centre,'_variete_', variete, sep='')
  system(paste('mkdir ', name_folder, sep=''))
  count <- 0

  for(i in 1:length(DataF))
  {
    count <- count + 1
    name <- compt
    png(file = paste('/home/R/Fusion/',name_folder,'/',name, sep = ''))
    plot(DataF[,i] ~ column)
    dev.off()
  }  
}

data_analysis_num('all', Centre_4, DF, 'Column_name')
```

I've thought it could be due to my data, so I've tried to replace `plot(DataF[,i] ~ column)` with `column ~ column)` (column being a trusted column) and it still won't work as expected...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not sure if that is the issue... but shouldn't you loop over `1:ncol(DataF)`?

Comment: Your code is very confusing. First, your function has an argument `dataframe` which you don't seem to use anywhere. Instead, you use a variable `DataF` which you don't seem to define. Second, you use a variable `compt` which does not seem to be defined. Third, why are you incrementing `count` when you are incrementing `i` in the `for(...)` statement.